# Como transferir um arquivo com nome corrompido?

Tags: windows, codificação-de-caracteres, email, sistema-de-arquivos

Um cliente meu está com um problema para fazer upload de arquivo no meu sistema, e pelo que pude perceber é o arquivo dele que está com o nome corrompido (é relativamente comum, em sistemas Windows, o nome acentuado ou com caracteres estrangeiros exibir corretamente no Windows Explorer mas quando você tenta acessá-lo programaticamente ocorre erro de codificação de caracteres). Infelizmente, quando o mesmo é enviado por e-mail o Gmail faz o favor de corrigir o erro no nome automaticamente, de modo que não consigo reproduzir o erro no meu ambiente...

Existe algum meio relativamente simples de enviar por e-mail um arquivo de modo que seu nome (incluindo quaisquer erros de codificação) seja preservado? De preferência algo que não exija muito conhecimento técnico, que eu possa simplesmente dizer pro meu cliente "faça X, depois Y, e me mande o resultado".

**Atualização:** no meu caso particular, o problema estava em outro lugar, de modo que não preciso mais de uma resposta com nenhuma urgência. Mas vou manter a pergunta, pois é um problema que já enfrentei outras vezes, e uma resposta pode ser útil ao tentar depurar problemas de *encoding* remotamente (quando é custoso ir até o cliente para pegar o arquivo direto da máquina dele).

Comment: Daria para fazer .zip do ficheiro e mandar o zip para inspecionares?

Comment: @Sergio Pedi pro meu cliente fazer isso também. Não sei se vai funcionar (só descobrirei amanhã, quando ele me enviar) pois o zip pode alterar o nome de alguma forma, mas é uma possibilidade...

Comment: Vou sugerir que se for compactar, coloque antes num(a) diretório/pasta. Diminui as chances de haver um *auto-fix* pelo compactador.

Answer (score 1):

Remetente:

> 1. Coloque o arquivo com nome corrompido dentro de um arquivo ZIP.
> 2. Renomeie o arquivo de forma a trocar a extensão dele para ZUP ou ZAP ou alguma outra coisa que o GMail não saiba o que é.
> 3. Envie o arquivo como anexo em um e-mail.

Destinatário:

> 1. Receba o e-mail e baixa o arquivo anexo.
> 2. Conserte a extensão do arquivo de volta para ZIP.
> 3. Extraia de dentro do arquivo ZIP, o arquivo original.